# Union of conjugates in free groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, free-groups

Let $F$ be a (finitely generated) free group, $H \leq F$ of infinite index. Is it possible that $$ \bigcup_{g \in F} gHg^{-1} = F?$$

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34044/group-cannot-be-the-union-of-conjugates shows a group can be a union of conjugates of proper subgroups. Write that group as a quotient of a free group and take preimages.

Comment: You are right (I have edited the question now), but I am mainly interested in the finitely generated case. Can something like that happen there?

Comment: The answer is "No" is $H$ is finitely generated. Namely, a f.g. free group cannot be equal to the union of conjugates of a proper f.g. subgroup. This is because any f.g. subgroup $H$ of a free group $F$ is closed in the profinite topology, hence there is a map $\phi$ from $F$ onto a finite group $K$ s.t. $\phi(H) \neq K$. From the result for finite groups, mentioned in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34044 , it follows that $K$ cannot be equal to the union of conjugates of $\phi(H)$, which implies the same about $F$ and $H$.

Comment: Yes this was clear to me. In fact, this is true if $H$ is merely contained in a proper open subgroup.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem of characterizing groups that are union of conjugates of a proper subgroup was considered in some papers by Wiegold and others.
In particular, you can look at

[*Transitive groups with fixed point free permutations*](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01224701), Archiv der Mathematik **27** (1976), 473-475.

[*Groups covered by conjugated of proper subgroups*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869305001420), Journal of Algebra **293** (2005), 261–268.

It turns out that the answer to your question is **yes**.

In fact, already the free group on two generators $F_2 = \langle a, b \rangle$ can be covered by the conjugates of one of its proper subgroups. This is shown in the first paper linked above, see Example 3.1 page 474.